# Can't disable turbo boost since Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, cpu, turbo-boost

I've recently updated to Ubuntu latest LTS. My computer suffers from bad cooling management, and I need to be able to disable turbo boost in order to use it comfortably.

I had a script that was doing just that by using msr-tools, disabling turbo boost on all cores with :

```
sudo wrmsr -pX 0x1a0 0x4000850089 (X being the number of the core)
```

Since the update this is what I get with this command:

```
wrmsr: pwrite: Operation not permitted
```

Any clue on how to fix this?

Regards

Comment: See: http://askubuntu.com/questions/789888/wrmsr-not-working-since-upgrade-to-ubuntu-16-04/790277#790277 The solution for me was to upgrade to kernel 4.6.2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I couldn't get my script to work with the latest version of msr-tools (probably discontinued as the github remains untouched since 2013). Perhaps Ubuntu 16.04 changed the way it stores settings for its CPUs drivers, and msr-tools fails to generate the proper file tree.

The workaround I found is to (sudo) edit the file:

```
/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/no_turbo
```

Simply type "1" for no turbo and save... No reboot needed.

You can easily check if it's working with

```
grep MHz /proc/cpuinfo
```

And see if any of the outputs goes above stock frequency

```
cpu MHz     : 2000.000
cpu MHz     : 2000.078
cpu MHz     : 2000.000
cpu MHz     : 1999.921
cpu MHz     : 1999.921
cpu MHz     : 1683.828
cpu MHz     : 1732.265
cpu MHz     : 2000.078
```

I hope someone will find this useful!
Regards

Comment: On Linux Mint 18.3, this solution works just for a session. When I reboot, `/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/no_turbo` is set again to `0`. Does anyone know how to make this change permanent?

Comment: I no longer use this, I can't recall if my workaround was permanent.. But I guess you could always script it at boot time

Comment: I also thought of doing this but I was hoping for a more elegant solution. Thanks for the tip anyway, Fluffy.