# wrmsr not working since upgrade to Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04

Since upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04, I have not been able to get wrmsr working on any address:

```
$ sudo rdmsr 0x1a4
0
$ sudo wrmsr 0x1a4 0
wrmsr: pwrite: Operation not permitted
```

There was a similar question in this site but the accepted answer provides a workaround only for Turbo Boost:

[Can't disable turbo boost since Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/764204/cant-disable-turbo-boost-since-ubuntu-16-04)

Any Ideas? Is this somehow related to capabilities?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a workaround by upgrading my kernel from the default (4.4.0-24-generic):

```
$ sudo rdmsr 0x1a4
rdmsr: open: No such file or directory
$ sudo modprobe msr
$ sudo rdmsr 0x1a4
0
$ sudo wrmsr 0x1a4 0
$ uname -r
4.6.0-040600-generic
```

I also confirmed it on 4.6.2:

```
$ uname -r
4.6.2-040602-generic
```

I later reproduced it again on 4.4.0-24-generic.

Comment: Does not really help as this I have this problem with kernel 4.13.0-38-generic again...

Answer (score 0):

It was my understanding that rdmsr and wrmsr use the msr kernel module to read/write via /dev/cpu/0/msr - is that module installed?

```
sudo modprobe msr
sudo wrmsr 0x1a4 0
```

Comment: Yes, the module is installed (confirmed with: lsmod | grep msr).

Comment: I can confirm this does not work even with the kernel module installed and using su rights. There is supposedly a workaround by [allowing a specific executable to use wrmsr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18661976/reading-dev-cpu-msr-from-userspace-operation-not-permitted), but it does not work for me either...